# jQuery select the link contains a url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assume I have this url:

```
<a href=​"/​browse/​buy/​?departments=1">​Phones​</a>​
```

And I want to match it via jQUery, the problem is, link is a subset of the queried test as this as I want to use the absolute path of the current page to find the fitting link (as my page may contain more additional get parameters like `/​browse/​buy/​?departments=1&order_by=title`:

Yet None of them worked:

```
$( 'a[href*="/​browse/​buy/​?departments=1&order_by=title"]' );

$( 'a[href^="/​browse/​buy/​?departments=1&order_by=title"]' );

$( 'a[href$="/​browse/​buy/​?departments=1&order_by=title"]' );
```

Comment: You want to find if the link has the `departments=1` *and* contains with `/browse/buy/`? If not, can you please clearly explain the requirements that you have?

Comment: If we are to assume the element at the top, why would you make the selector more specific so as to exclude the given element? I can't tell what your actual issue is. How does using the absolute path of the current page factor in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to find if the link has the `departments=1` and contains with `/browse/buy/`, use this:

```
$('a[href*="/​browse/​buy/"][href*="departments=1"]');
```